# Why was this question closed? Has this place gone insane?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[DB schema for packaging products/services together under a single price/offer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180986/best-approach-for-a-combo-selling-site-with-mysql-and-php)

This is straight up design question!
Granted it could have been writing better, I didn't fully understand what he was asking at first. **But Off Topic**???

Comment: "I didn't fully understand what he was asking at first" <-- How about we fix this (edit, edit, edit!)?

Comment: Then What? Get 4 more votes?? Its easier to re-ask!

Comment: No, it's not easier to re-ask. For starters there are only 3 downvotes (the fourth one is automatic and will be removed if the question is re-opened), and such a small number of downvotes almost always disappears (and even gets reversed to upvotes) when a closed question is improved and re-opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was one of the close-voters so I'll just explain why that's so.

Basically, after reading the question for the first time, it sounded like 70% business question and 30% database design question. Now that is probably because the question was poorly worded and difficult to understand. Personally, I did not edit it because I wasn't sure what he was trying to ask. All I knew was that it sounded off-topic in it's current form.

Honestly, after your edit, it is much more clear what the OP is asking, and I have cast my reopen vote. Thanks for the clarification Morons!